# React Native - ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently making a registration form using React Native. When I implement  into the application, a scroll bar doesn't work.

```
return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <View style={styles.registerTextContainer}>
              {/* <Text style={styles.registerText}>Register for an account</Text> */}
            </View>

            <Form type={User} ref={c => (this._form = c)} options={options} />

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.registerButtonContainer}
              onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
              <Text style={styles.registerButtonText}>REGISTER</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

[This is how the application currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM0G0.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't set flex:1 in scroll view, instead try

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying wrapping the whole page with ScrollView instead of TouchableWithoutFeedback and set flex to 1

```
 return (
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }}
  >
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <View style={styles.registerTextContainer}>
          {/* <Text style={styles.registerText}>Register for an account</Text> */}
        </View>

        <Form type={User} ref={(c) => (this._form = c)} options={options} />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.registerButtonContainer}
          onPress={this.handleSubmit}
        >
          <Text style={styles.registerButtonText}>REGISTER</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</ScrollView>
```

);

Comment: Unfortunately no results :( The slider doesn't show up even though I have the formContainer set to height: 800 which should extend below the page